# Xcode has an error after connecting to the phone

Tags: xcode

I connected my iPhone on Xcode11.4.1, normal used but have an error: Failed _shouldMakeReadyForDevelopment check even though the device is not locked by a passcode.

```
allowsSecureServices: 1. isConnected: 0. Platform: <DVTPlatform:0x7fe0e0db00e0:'com.apple.platform.iphoneos':<DVTFilePath:0x7fe0e0db0060:'/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform'>>. DTDKDeviceIdentifierIsIDID: 0
```

Error image:

[image]

Comment: How is the phone connected?

Comment: Connected by wire, also opened the ‘connect via network’

Comment: And it’s a straight connect via usb-c? There is some chat that the physical connection might be the issue

Comment: Yes, it is directly connected via USB-C. Thank you for your answer, I'll check it out later